# reload the useEffect function when post data : reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have this useEffect which has a get function and have a function called `sentchat` which has an axios.post method to post some data the data which I am posting through post method is fetched in the useffect method axios get but I have to reload the page to see the posted data I want it to happen automatically

```
 function sentchat(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    };
    const data = { receiver: props.id, message: inputField };
    axios
      .post("messages/send-message/", data, config)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.receiverDetails);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    };

    axios
      .get("messages/get-all-messages/?receiver=" + props.id, config)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.receiverDetails);
        setdata(res.data.receiverDetails);
        setMessage(res.data.messages);
      });
  }, [props.id]);
```

Comment: what you can do is executing the code in useEffect in sentchat function once the post is successful. better to put the code to a function and you can reuse it like function fetchData() {...}.  then call the function in useEffect(()=>{fetchData()},[]) and in sentchat function as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer.

Add a ref (I will explain why later on)

```
    const mountedRef = useRef(true)
```

Change your useEffect to this

```
      useEffect(() => {
        if(mountedRef.current){
          getData();
        }
        return function cleanup() {
          mountedRef.current = false
        };
      }, [getData]);
```

We are going to add a new callback

```
    const getData = useCallback(async () => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    };
        const res = await axios.get("messages/get-all-messages/?receiver=" + props.id, config)
        //Also adding to check we have a response otherwise you will be setting the state of undefined which will crash.
        if(res.status === 200){
         //We use the ref here to confirm that this component is still mounted otherwise you will get leak errors.
          if(mountedRef.current){
             console.log(res.receiverDetails);
             setdata(res.data.receiverDetails);
             setMessage(res.data.messages);
          }
        }
      }, [])
```

Now you can call getData() whenever you need to.

So just add this to your post response

```
 function sentchat(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    };
    const data = { receiver: props.id, message: inputField };
    axios
      .post("messages/send-message/", data, config)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.receiverDetails);
        //ADD LINE HERE
        getData()
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: how can data trigger an event when there isn't any setState call in send chat method?

Comment: ??? In the response he calls ```setData(res.data.receiverDetails);```

Comment: @matt_roki2 i tryed ur answer but it becomes endless loop of api calls i  want it to happen only ones

Comment: @meon Yeah let me update my answer to fix the loop give me 5 to type it

Comment: okee  take ur time @matt_roki2

Comment: @meon Check now. Added some extra bits to help you with future calls

Comment: Forgot to add your config so just added that

Comment: @matt_roki2 thanks for the answer but this is not working . i was passing `props.id` from  parrent js file to show data based on each id after adding this  ` axios.get("messages/get-all-messages/?receiver=" + props.id, config)` is not working

Comment: i think if   getData()  reloads on  when ever  props.id     change it will become correct